# Dart analyser const on constructor inside the class

Tags: dart

Inside dart analyser, there is [prefer_const_constructors](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/prefer_const_constructors).

But, this rules apply to when calling the class.

There is no dart analyser rule to not forget to write const inside the constructor ?

Like :

BAD:

```
class A {
  A();
}
```

GOOD:

```
class A {
  const A();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Correct. If you want a change to the analyzer, or more likely adding an optional lint to recommend making constructors constant if they can be, then you should file an issue in the [linter repo](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues).

Comment: Ok thanks, asked here : https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/4712